# Remove Divs from webpage using validation

Tags: html

I am looking for a way to remove DIV's from a website when it loads. The website is not local, it's a live site. It also recognises that Adblock is installed and prompts these DIV's until it is disabled.

I was looking at using the Adblock Plus filters but I don't know how I would accomplish the removal of the DIVs because their characteristics are not the same, each time the webpage loads. Here is some info on the site. I will also provide a screenshot of what exactly I would like to remove.

**Name of website**: http://www.tweaktown.com/

**Element to remove**: Multiple DIV Elements

- The DIV's are generated with random Class' and ID's.
- There are DIVs within other DIVs that need to be deleted.
- Image showing DIVs/IDs and Validation[image: Image showing DIVs/IDs and Validation]

I'm hoping there Is some way to validate against the

tags strings as shown in the Image

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. Currently this is just a request for work - that belongs more on e-lance.com than here. Also you want to remove the request to not have the ads blocked? That is not very nice now is it?

Comment: To simply remove the elements you could use an on-load JS running plugin, e.g. Tampermonkey (Chrome) or Greasemonkey (Firefox) and some basic JS. However there's a high chance that the actual content behind those divs isn't displayed if you don't view their ads, specificaly to prevent what you're trying to do,  so removing them may not do you any good.

Comment: @mplungjan Didn't request for work at all. I will implement it. How am I supposed to post code when I have no idea how this sort of thing would work. Would you like me to write out the paragraphs for validation. I thought guys here would like to get involved in helping. You know.... looking at the site. Here, I'll save you all that work of clicking one link in my next comment.

Hmm not very nice is it not? Sorry, but clearly you have never used the site without an ad-blocker. Therefore I'm not going to take you've judgement about weather it's nice or not into account.
Thanks DBS :)

Comment: Validation:
__<p>We rely on advertising to offer our journalism for free.</p>__  __<p>Please consider disabling your ad blocker or watching a video ad to support us.</p>__

Comment: @DBS Hi, I know from experience that this site does allow you to view its content without the ads. Previously, AdBlocker worked. However, the created functionality to recognise when it was used and then implemented code to stop the user viewing it, if you have adblocker.  
  
However, if you remove those DIVs manually, this site still functions as expected. It's simply stamped on each page on the site.  

It's worth mentioning that I wouldn't block ads from sites that have a reasonable amount of quality control for the user. When a site consumes 1GB+ of RAM, there's no way I'm having it.

Comment: If you use their site, perhaps click on a couple of ads before blocking them entirely, I hate ads as well but running a site isn't free and people are trying to make a living. That being said, you can match that stack of  ads popups using `$("div:contains('you are using an ad blocker')")` I'll let you figure out the rest

Comment: @Lewis - I was just giving you information on why this question might be voted down and closed. If you search on "remove div from DOM" you will find a lot of methods to start you off. Then you can post that code and explain what did not work for you. But currently your question is off topic for SO. What I do if I do not want to see such overlay is just inspect and delete it - in your case the one with class kulawvpa

Comment: @DBS Thanks again :)